# Service discovery for win docker containers on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I run Windows and Linux containers on AWS ECS cluster using both deployment types (Fargate/EC2) . For each container I created a load balancer target group, so I can route the traffic using application load balancer. I use awsvpc network mode, so each container has its private IP address, but the address can always change.

But I'd like to communicate between services without using a load balancer, if possible. Based on that [thread](https://github.com/aws/aws-app-mesh-roadmap/issues/298) it doesn't look like AppMesh is supported for Windows and that was my first try...

Any ideas how to communicate services? or is the application load balancer the only option? Any performance considerations I should take into account?

Comment: Have you looked at AWS CloudMap? It is purely DNS based, so it would work fine with your Windows containers, and it is even integrated into ECS. https://aws.amazon.com/cloud-map/

Comment: I just figured out, that I can set up service discovery settings in my ECS service definition and it will register the container/service under the provided name in my namespace

Comment: Yes, that is using AWS CloudMap.

Answer (score 0):

as @Mark B  mentioned in the comment, I should use AWS CloudMap, since it's purely DNS based.

I tested the solution and it works perfectly fine for me. Issue is solved